# A/C shuts off periodically; switch off and back on and will work again

Tags: ac, volvo

My Volvo XC90 runs well but periodically its A/C will shut off. I turn off the a/c for 30 seconds, then turn back on and seems to work well again. Could this be a compressor issue? Someone mentioned a low level of refrigerant?

Comment: How long between having to turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

Does the air blow cold?  When refrigerant gets low air blows hot.  You can always buy a can of refrigerant with the installation nozzle, check the pressure and if low fill or if not return for refund.  This should help you start to diagnose your problem and check possibilities off the list.
From my experience the heater/ AC controller can go bad, swapping with a new controller deck in the dash fixes the problem.  Sometimes the AC fan overheats on import vehicles.  This causes the fan to shut off and the AC turns off as a result.  The fan will usually become louder as it gets closer to the end of its life.   Also the compressor will not kick on until there is enough pressure in the system as a safety feature to stop the compressor from failing due to lack of refrigerant or lubrication.  Even if the compressor kicks on but it blows hot, usually means low refrigerant level.  Hope this helps